# Update DIV depending on signed in status?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I currently have a `<ul>` in my navigation area which holds a `<%= render :partial => "sessions/manager" %>` which basically calls another partial which depending on the users login status renders either a login form or a welcome statement.

My login section is powered by ajx and so refreshes automaticlly. Here's the code im using.

**login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form#sign_in').bind('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data.success) {
      $('.user_nav').html(data.content);
    } else {
      $('.user_nav').prepend(data.errors.join('<br />'));
    }
  });

});
```

Now I want another div on my page containing various links to either hide or show depending on the users logged in status.

Currently my code is this.

```
<% if(signed_in?) %>
  <li><%= link_to "Clients", "/clients"  %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Jobs", "/jobs"  %></li> 
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

However, this doesn't work how id like. The links don't show at first which is cool BUT the links don't show again when im signed in... unless I do a full page refresh.

How can I ajax-ify this section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CSS's Visibility property instead, that's less secure, because anyone can see Links in source code, but will works smoothly.

and if in JSP, try reloading page through that code, inside that if, that will look like sign in, is in progress and meanwhile your page will be refreshed.

Comment: how would I reload the page using javascript? Can't I just reload the div/li class item?

Comment: window.location.href="Type_URL_of_Current_Page" 
and if just part if HTML then

Comment: Use IFrames , and inside that IFrame's referenced page, *which will have your links* Refresh that page , so it will look like just part of Page s refreshed.

Comment: And if you dont going with frames than, use jQuery, that will help *if yu want to do it easily*

Comment: `$("#content").load(location.href+" #content>*","");`
Ref :  http://blog.mediasoft.be/partial-page-refresh-with-ajax-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

---

Your example doesn't work as the server has to render the page again to pass signed_in?

I would recommend to get rid of the ajax login and just make a normal submit and reload the page without ajax.
If you still want to use ajax, there would be the possibility to make a page reload with javascript:

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

or

```
window.location.reload()
```

But then you can also make a normal submit and everything should work fine.

Never do this with css visibility! It's really unsecure and not a good programming behaviour. The server have to validate and send the right html to the user, depending if he is logged in or not.